# Automatically copy when something is selected. Python

Tags: python, copy, clipboard

I'm trying to write a little program that when activated performs a <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> as soon as text is selected.

Alternatively, just performs a <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> over and over again until the user deactivate the script.

Comment: Welcome to [so]! What have you tried? Please review [ask].

Comment: Is this intended to work across any application?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [OS X Get highlighted text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1151417/os-x-get-highlighted-text)

Comment: @JoeIddon: I doubt it's a duplicate of that, because that's about OS X, and Ctrl+C doesn't copy on OS X; it's Cmd+C.

Comment: By the way, performing a Ctrl+C over and over may not be a good idea. On both Windows and *nix (OS X, Linux, etc.), if the input is going to a terminal program, Ctrl+C doesn't mean "copy", it means "kill the program".

Comment: @abarnert or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7082027/python-get-selected-text

Comment: Who upvotes such a, well, it is not even a question.